# How to impute or predict a characteristic when one of the IVs in the prediction is other household members having that same characteristic?

Tags: regression, sampling, predictive-models, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

In some data set A, we have: household id, person id, age, sex, and then a simple binary `likes donuts / does not like donuts` variable.
In some other data set B, we have just household id, person id, age, and sex.

We have set up a regression in data set A with independent variables: age, sex, and `does anyone in the household like donuts?` in order to predict who likes donuts in data set B.
People living in households where *anyone* likes donuts are more likely to like donuts themselves, so we don't want to throw out that *intra*-household probability when imputing donut likeage.

However, I'm unclear how to implement something computationally that maintains these within-household donut affinities when we're imputing `do you like donuts` in data set B?
Do we impute at the household-level first, and then impute a subset of the people within sampled households?  I feel like I should take a page out of the cluster sampling playbook, but I'm not really sure where to start looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to model sex and age predicting donut liking using a multi-level logistic regression where you have additional random effects and intercept nested within household. e.g.

```
lmer(donutLiking ~ sex * age + (sex * age | household), data = A)
```

From that you can get parameters that allow you to make probabilistic statements about the donut liking in data set B both taking into account cross household variability and random and fixed effects of sex and age

Comment: wait, i'm sorry, let's assume data sets A and B are both sampled the same way from the same population..  so the rate of intra-household donut likingness should be the same in both data sets.

Comment: ..i guess i'm confused.  if data set A has a thousand households and data set B also has a thousand households, why wouldn't you know anything about within-household variability?